# How can I provide new behavior to an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I would like to modify the behavior of a class instance that implements a particular interface. The modification is performed by a modifier object. In the end, the original class instance should still retain all of its other behavior. Here's the setup:

The interfaces and implementing class look like this:

```cs
interface IFuncA
{
  double DoSomethingA();
}
interface IFuncB
{
  int DoSomethingB(string str);
}

class ImplementsAB : IFuncA, IFuncB
{
  void DoSomethingA() => 3.14;
  int DoSomethingB(string str) => str.Length;
}
```

There is some modifier class that works according to the following psuedocode. This is the part that I can't exactly figure out.

```cs
// Unknown how to make this work.
class ModifiesFuncB
{
  int Multiplier;
  int ModifiedDoSomethingB(string str) => Multiplier * str.Length;

  ModifiesFuncB(int multiplier)
  {
    Multiplier = multiplier;
  }

  T Modify<T>(T funcB) where T : IFuncB
  {
    // This is pseudo-code.
    funcB.DoSomethingB = ModifiedDoSomethingB;
    return funcB;
  }
}
```

Here is some sample code using the modifier to modify the behavior of the `IFuncB` interface on an object that implements it.

```cs
ImplementsAB myObj = new ImplementsAB();
ModifiesFuncB modifier = new ModifiesFuncB(2);

Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingA());        // Outputs 3.14
Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingB("hello")); // Outputs 5

myObj = modifier.Modify(myObj);

Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingA());        // Outputs 3.14
Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingB("hello")); // Outputs 10
```

**Is there a solution, software design pattern, or common method of doing this?** This could be the entirely wrong way to things but demonstrating what I should do instead would be a great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could have a property: Func<string, int> DoSomethingB { get; set; } in your class that hold the function that you currently need.

Comment: There is one issue with the interface you provided: if `Modify` returns `IFuncB` then the assignment to `myObj` is impossible - you cannot assign `IFuncB` to `ImplementsAB`. Please clarify the behaviour you want, because if you expect to be able to do that assignment then the problem is a bit more complicated than if you don't.

Comment: For starters this code does not compile not only in the "pseudocode" part. `ImplementsAB` is invalid, `myObj = modifier.Modify(myObj);` also is invalid due to type mismatch. Also it looks more like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you explain why do you want something like this, may be there are better options?

Comment: @spzvtbg I could do that. I think I'd prefer not to because some of these interfaces may be very complex with a variety of types of functions.

Comment: @V0ldek Sure thing. You're completely right. I'll modify my question to use a generic there so that it's possible. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @GuruStron You're right. I fixed my question after someone else pointed out the same issue. I don't think my attempted solution is incorrect now. The reason I want to do this is because I have multiple modifiers (instances of `ModifiesFuncB`) with parameters specified by users acting on multiple objects of which all I know is whether or not they implement `IFuncB`. As I said in my post, there probably are better options which is why I ask. If there's no good solution to this problem, I'll have to search for another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classically, the design pattern you'd be looking for is [Decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator). Basically you'd want to create a new instance that wraps the original instance and modifies its behaviour while retaining the same interface. There is an issue with that, namely that you want to call the `Modify` on a concrete class `ImplementsAB` and expect the result to still be of that type `ImplementsAB`. That's pretty much impossible to do in general. Let me state that in a bit more formal terms.

You want a method `T Modify<T>(T t) where T : IFuncB` that modifies the behaviour of `T` without knowing what class that is exactly. This is rather visibly impossible, since the only thing you know about `IFuncB` is that it has the `int DoSomethingB(string)` method. You could achieve what you want with some reflection voodoo by creating a class extending `T` at runtime (provided `T` is not sealed), but that's more of a fun excercise than something you'd want to put in production.

I see two ways out of this.

### 1. Easy way out

If you can relax the interface and expect the method to be `IFuncB Modify(IFuncB funcB)` then a classical Decorator pattern applies (I extended the IFuncB interface to show how the pattern works in general):

```
interface IFuncB
{
  int DoSomethingB(string str);
  void DoSomethingElse();
}

class ModifiesFuncB
{
  int Multiplier { get; }
  int ModifiedDoSomethingB(string str) => Multiplier * str.Length;

  ModifiesFuncB(int multiplier)
  {
    Multiplier = multiplier;
  }

  IFuncB Modify(IFuncB funcB) => return new ModifiedFuncB(funcB, Multiplier);

  private class ModifiedFuncB : IFuncB
  {
    private readonly int _multiplier;
    private readonly IFuncB _impl;

    public ModifiedFuncB(IFuncB impl, int multiplier) =>
      (_impl, _multiplier) = (impl, multiplier);

    public int DoSomethingB(string str) => _multiplier * str.Length;

    public void DoSomethingElse() => _impl.DoSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

You create a wrapper that modifies the behaviour you want and routes everything else to the original instance. Very useful pattern.

### 2. Explicitly implement what you want

The only reasonable solution I can find for the original problem is to require the original implementation to enable such modification.

First, define an interface that enables modification explicitly:

```
interface ICanBeModifiedB<TFrom> where TFrom : IFuncB
{
    TFrom Modify(IFuncB modifier);
}
```

The semantics are: this object's implementation of `IFuncB` can be modified by calling `Modify` with an implementation of the new desired behaviour.

Second, create a base implementation in an abstract class so that people don't have to implement it all from scratch for every class:

```
abstract class CanBeModifiedB<TFrom> : IFuncB, ICanBeModifiedB<TFrom> where TFrom : IFuncB
{
    private IFuncB? _modifier;

    protected abstract TFrom This { get; }

    public TFrom Modify(IFuncB impl)
    {
        _modifier = impl;
        return This;
    }

    public int DoSomethingB(string str) => 
       _modifier is null ? DoSomethingBImpl(str) : _modifier.DoSomethingB(str);

    public int DoSomethingElseB() => 
       _modifier is null ? DoSomethingElseB() : _modifier.DoSomethingElseB();
    
    protected abstract int DoSomethingBImpl(string str);
    protected abstract void DoSomethingElseBImpl();
}
```

If `Modify` was not called, the operations are routed to the original implementation. After a modifier is given, all `IFuncB` operations are routed to that modifier.

Finally, implement the remaining abstract members:

```
class ImplementsAB : IFuncA, CanBeModifiedB<ImplementsAB>
{
  protected override ImplementsAB This => this;

  protected double DoSomethingA() => 3.14;
  protected override int DoSomethingBImpl(string str) => str.Length;
  protected override void DoSomethingElseImpl() => Console.WriteLine("Something.");
}
```

Finally, to show it all in action:

```
class ModifiedB : ImplementsAB
{
    private readonly int _multiplier;
    
    public ModifiedB(int multiplier) => _multiplier = multiplier;
    
    protected override int DoSomethingBImpl(string str) => _multiplier * str.Length;
}

ImplementsAB myObj = new ImplementsAB();
ModifiesFuncB modifier = new ModifiesFuncB(2);

Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingA());        // Outputs 3.14
Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingB("hello")); // Outputs 5

myObj = modifier.Modify(myObj);

Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingA());        // Outputs 3.14
Console.WriteLine(myObj.DoSomethingB("hello")); // Outputs 10
```

You can find [full code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gBDaZr).

Comment: Awesome answer. I think this explains what I've been trying to figure out and I'm glad that I'm not crazy for thinking this seems to be impossible in the way I was attempting it. I think the method #2 works well in my entire codebase so I'll try to go about it that way. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewMiller Note that it's not _entirely_ impossible. Entity Framework implements lazy loading by creating Proxy types at runtime that inherit from user-defined entities. .NET gives you tools to do this via `System.Reflection.Emit` and the [`TypeBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=net-5.0). But it is stupidly complex and contrived enough to make any other solution more desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the

**Decorator pattern** - "*Attach additional resposibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality.*" (Gamma, Erich, et al. "Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software." Design Patterns. massachusetts: Addison-Wesley Publishing Company (1995)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the method in ImplementsAB.
For example

```
interface IFuncA
{
    double DoSomethingA();
}


interface IFuncB
{
    int DoSomethingB(string str);
}


class ImplementsAB : IFuncA, IFuncB
{
    public virtual int DoSomethingB(string str)
    {
        return 222222;
    }

    public double DoSomethingA()
    {
        return 333333;
    }
}


class ModifiesFuncB : ImplementsAB
{
    // Do whatever you want here and override the method when you want to use it with different behavior
    public override int DoSomethingB(string str)
    {
        return 999;
    }

}
```

You can see the Patterns Abstract Factory. You can set a different behavior to a class as well.
I have an example on my GitHub: https://github.com/renanslucena88/DesignPatterns

I hope I've helped a bit.

Comment: This is nice but in my setting I have multiple instances that all I know about them is they implement `IFuncB` not necessarily that they are of type `ImplementsAB`. Thanks though!